# Passing components/JSX as a prop to the child component without using this.props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to create a helper component that would help me check if the user has the permission to carry out a certain action. This helper component is called `PermissionsChecker` and it will wrap around the JSX of interest.

The issue im facing now is that i wish to be able to specify some JSX to be rendered if the check fails , for example , some jsx containing texts that they are not authorized.

Heres the code to further illuminate on the problem:

```
class PermissionsChecker extends Component {
    checkperms(){
       //code which checks the user's permissions list
    }
    
    render() {
        if(this.checkperms() === true){
        return (
            this.props.children //<-- i will return whatever JSX it was wrapping.
            )}
        else{
        return(
            (this.props.replacement?
                <Fragment>
               {this.props.replacement}  //<--- here is where i wish to return the JSX if check fails
                </Fragment>
            )
        )
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the helper function in action:

```
<PermissionsChecker
   codeNames={['view_salesprojec2t']}
   replacement={<Text>{id}</Text>} >
   <Link to={`/project/detail/${id}`}>
   {id}
   </Link>
</PermissionsChecker>
```

As you can see , `this.props.children` will not be a solution for me as i am already utilizing that to return the original JSX. What i wish to do is to add the ability to specify the JSX in the replacement prop and then returning it back from my `PermissionsChecker` component if the check passes.

I have tried to console log `this.props.replacement` and I am recieving this :

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: null
props:
children: 1
__proto__: Object
ref: null
type: ƒ Text(_a)
_owner: FiberNode {tag: 11, key: null, elementType: {…}, type: {…}, stateNode: null, …}
_store: {validated: false}
_self: CustomerDetail {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, _reactInternalFiber: FiberNode, …}
__proto__: Object
```

Is there a good fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Passing a constructed component (`<Component/>`) throught props is an anti-pattern.

Instead, you should use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) on `props.children`, while checking the condition on component's level (instead of using `PermissionsChecker`):

```
<>
  {checkPermissions() ? (
    <Link to={`/project/detail/${id}`}>{id}</Link>
  ) : (
    <Text>{id}</Text>
  )}
</>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it may be considered an antipattern?

Comment: You calculate the component even though it may not be used. If you going this way better to pass a function instead and render the component on demand.

Comment: Ah okay , i will heed your advice and convert it into a global function instead